# jquery mobile - set select/option values

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, html-select

am trying to set select/option values using jquery Mobile and can't seem to get it working.

```
<!-- Complete example below. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="mainmenu">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
    <h1>Main Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-body ui-body-c">
    <div data-role="content">   
        <div id='placeholderA' ></div>  
        <div id='placeholderB' ></div>  
    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit"  id="addPart" data-theme="a" data-icon="plus">Add Serial/Part</button></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>         

<script>        

    var currentTab = "A";       

    // An XML fragment
    testXML =  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\
    <Doc>\
        <DtlFields>\
            <ACTC>B</ACTC>\
            <QTY>5</QTY>\
        </DtlFields>\
        <DtlFields>\
            <ACTC>A</ACTC>\
            <QTY>6</QTY>\
        </DtlFields>\
    </Doc>";

    // An HTML fragment
    section = "<ul data-role='listview' data-theme='a'>\
            <li>PART: <span class='thisSection'></span>\
            <div data-role='fieldcontain'>\
                <label>A Label</label>\
                <select name='ACTC' id='preAction' data-theme='a'>\
                <option value='A'>A</option>\
                <option value='B'>B</option>\
                <option value='C'>C</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
            </li>\
            </ul>\
            <!-- ***   Quantity     *** -->\
            <div data-role='fieldcontain'>\
                <label>QTY</label>\
                <input type='range' name='QTY' id='preQuant01' value='1' min='1' max='10'/>\
            </div>\
        </div>";


$(document).ready(function () {

    /* Add a listeners to ADD PART */   
        $('#addPart').click(function() {                                
            var xml = $($.parseXML(testXML));           
            xml.find("DtlFields").each(function () {
                var XMLString= $(this);             
                fnAddPart(XMLString);                               
            });     
            return false;
        });   

    // add a part section to a Group on screen
    function fnAddPart(XMLString){
        myTmpl = $(section);                                                    

        if (XMLString != "" ){

            // set Quantity - this works
            var x =((XMLString).find("QTY").text());
            myTmpl.find("input[name='QTY']").attr('value', x);          

            // ************ set Activity - but this does not work! ***************
            var x =((XMLString).find("ACTC").text());           
            myTmpl.find("input[name='ACTC']").attr('value', x); 

        }       
        // append to page
        myTmpl.appendTo("#placeholder"+currentTab).page();                                                      
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 68):

When programmatically manipulating elements like `select` fields in jQuery Mobile, once you've made the relevant selection, you need to refresh the element so that the user interface is updated. Here's an example snippet which sets a value in a `select` field, and then updates it:

```
// Grab a select field
var el = $('#YOUR_SELECT_FIELD');

// Select the relevant option, de-select any others
el.val('some value').attr('selected', true).siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');

// jQM refresh
el.selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

So it's that last line I suspect you need.

Comment: `el.val('some value')` isn't this returning the `select` element itself and not a option? at least that's what it does for me ?

Comment: No: var el = $('#YOUR_SELECT_FIELD'); is the <select> group. el.val('some value') gets you the <option> within that <select> with a value="some value"

Comment: (Amused by two down-votes for this -- both on the same day -- some three years after the event).

Comment: really nice one liner ben

Comment: YES. Tried 20 other options, this finally did it.

Comment: Do a `el.change();` at the end if you want to trigger an `onchange` handler on the select list.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases you might need to wrap your function to execute on document.ready and initialize the selectmenu. Here is my solution using Ben Poole's example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Grab a select field
var el = $('#YOUR_SELECT_FIELD');

// Select the relevant option, de-select any others
el.val('some value').attr('selected', true).siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');

// Initialize the selectmenu
el.selectmenu();

// jQM refresh
el.selectmenu("refresh", true);
});
```